# Which nvidia driver should I use for an FX1300 on openSuse 11.2?

Tags: opensuse, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an nVidia FX1300 and can't figure out which driver to use on openSuse 11.2.  This card isn't listed for any of the [one-click installs](http://en.opensuse.org/NVIDIA_drivers).

I need version 173.14.22 of the driver.  Do any of the one-click installs contain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second one click install](http://opensuse-community.org/nvidia-fx5xxx.ymp) on that link installs x11-video-nvidiaG01 which is the 173 series driver.

NVIDIA have three driver versions - current (190.xx), "new" legacy (173.14.xx), "old" legacy (96.xx) - any of the 173 drivers will support your card.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download the driver directly from NVIDIA.](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index5.aspx?lang=en-us)
2. Stop X.
3. Run the installer as root (`sudo sh NVIDIA.....`)
4. Start X.
5. Done.

Comment: Yes, but I like using RPMs so that I don't have to manually reinstall the driver each time the kernel is updated.

Comment: You can (with some effort, I admit) hook the driver in with DKMS so the kernel mode driver is automatically rebuilt. See here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036788 (I know it's Ubuntu but I'm hoping the core principals are still the same).

Comment: The other option is to write a *very* small script that stops GDM, runs the installer with the quiet flag and starts x. When you do do a kernel update and reboot, you just have to run your script (taking 20-seconds) and you're good to go.